# Squares from 1 to 10000 that have a remainder of 2 when divided by 7

Tags: modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Find the number of integers $1\leq x\leq100$ such that $x^2$ has a remainder of $2$ when divided by $7$.

Comment: Finding the remainders for $1 \le x \le 15$ might give you a clue

Comment: any number $x \equiv 3,4$ mod $7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The sequence of remainders is

$$1,4,2,2,4,1,0,1,4,2,2,4,1,0,\cdots$$

The pattern should be obvious.